# Count number of rows edited by Stored Proc

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

We have a stored procedure in a MSSQL Server 2008 database that performs a number of reads and writes in response to user action on a website. 
I would like to know if there is any way of counting how many rows were edited/created during the procedure, preferably without having to alter the proc (although alterations are possible).
Does anyone have any suggestions? I looked at `@@ROWCOUNT` but that covers reads and writes (and I'd prefer not o go throught the proc and manually add up ROWCOUNT after each UPDATE)

EDIT: the proc is being called from C# using the System.Data.SqlClient classes

Comment: I think that's going to be the only way - make a `@ChangeCt` variable and increment it by `@@ROWCOUNT` after each statement.

Comment: `@@ROWCOUNT` only gives you an answer based on the last run statement also, so would only report on the last action that occurred inside the stored prcoedure

Comment: What are you using to call the stored procedure? I'm assuming that you're just not running it through SSMS, so what language / libraries are you using to call it?  Java? C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without editing the proc, your best bet would be to start a SQL Server Profiler session, track [SP:StmtCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189570.aspx), filter ObjectName to your proc, and filter TextData to the statements you want to monitor.  Be sure to include the RowCount column.

Note that you can't get the row counts from the [extended events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630282.aspx) sql_statement_completed event.  There is no row count column; just duration, CPU, reads and writes.

If you can edit the proc, you would have total control over the behavior.  You could sum up the [@@ROWCOUNT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx) of every INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE operation.  This count could be returned as an output parameter, written to the log, PRINTed, traced with [user-defined trace events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175164.aspx), saved to a table, etc.

Comment: so, is there any version of SQL, where extended events captures the RowCount ?

Answer (score 1):

MS Sql Profiler is where you want to start for something like this.

Answer (score 1):

@@ROWCOUNT will give you counts based on the last run statement, so with that you could  create a local variable and update it after everytime with @@ROWCOUNT

Otherwise you will have to get into Profiler and watch from there, but that is not a sustainable solution, better suited for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

I Have no idea about MySQL, But Oracle SQL provides a variable called  SQL%ROWCOUNT, which contains the number of rows effected in the immediately previous transaction